# Count the number of elements in a list

Tags: dolphindb

How to count the number of elements in a vector including the NULLs?

So far I have used **count()** function, but **count()** doesn’t count NULLs.

Comment: Use size(). Source: https://www.dolphindb.com/help/index.html?size.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count NULLs as well, use **size()** instead.
The function **count()** counts only NON-NULL values.